# YADCF 0.8.9 and DataTable 1.10 - language with url

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I've an issue with the option ScrollY in the two plugins YADCF 0.8.9 and DataTable 1.10.
I try to add some filters on my headers and to activate the option ScrollY but :
- With the option scrollY, I've no filter
- Without : works fine ! (obviously without "max height 400 px"

What can I do ?

JS :

```
    var tableDataTbl = $("#MyDataTableTest").DataTable({
        language: {
            url: '/js/DataTables/fr_FR.json'
        },
        scrollY: 400,
        paging : false,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        stateSave: true
    });

    yadcf.init(tableDataTbl, 
        [{
            column_number: 0,
            filter_type: "text"
        }, {
            column_number: 1,
            filter_type: "range_number"
        }, {
            column_number: 2,
            filter_type: "range_number"
        }, {
            column_number: 3,
            filter_type: "range_number"
        }, {
            column_number: 4,
            filter_type: "range_number"
        }, {
            column_number: 5,
            filter_type: "range_number"
        }, {
            column_number: 6,
            filter_type: "text"
        }, {
            column_number: 7,
            filter_type: "text"
        }]
    );
```

Comment: I think its because of the url: '/js/DataTables/fr_FR.json' , try placing the json content of that fr_FR.json directly into the table init - `language: {
            some_key: 'some text', ....
        }`, if it will solve this then please open an issue on yadcf, otherwise I wont remember to fix it...

Comment: if its indeed a scrollY issue - then post here a link to jsbin showing that

Comment: Thanks Daniel !!! Problem solved !

Comment: so it haws nothing to do with the scrolly, right ? its the language url that doing the problems to the yadcf? p.s I;m the author of yadcf

Comment: Yep, ajax JSON and language url is the problem ! ScrollY works perfectly now :) (and I've aborted JSON / Ajax for language, not necessary for me...)

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in [0.9.2.beta.2](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/d5dba790602738a234d4629596b1005c1d9fab56/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js)

[see test page](https://jsfiddle.net/6c660hat/74/)

It was an because of the `language: {url: '...'},` and the `scrollY: ...,` were used together, anyway - it works now